# Which makes for a better equivalent capacitor? In series or in parrallel?

Tags: classical-mechanics, electricity, electric-circuits, capacitance

I understand how capacitors in series and in parallel work. However, I am wondering if it makes a difference, in terms of making a better capacitor that can store more charge, would you connect them in series or in parallel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the other two answers are technically correct, they are not actually addressing the engineering aspects of what comprises a "good" capacitor. Ideal capacitors in parallel or series circuits lead to ideal capacitors of different value, i.e. there is no measurable "quality" difference - ideal is ideal.

In reality, of course, there are no ideal capacitors. Real capacitors have non-ideal behavior which will cause very severe problems in real circuits. I could give you a two hour "full download" about what those are in detail, but I have to say that this is really something that should be discussed in electrical engineering. To get you started, you have to think about the following first order problem:

1) Series resistance - a real capacitor has a non-trivial series resistance, which is usually in the $m\Omega$ to $1\Omega$ range. If you have to draw large currents from the capacitor, then this needs to be minimized, otherwise the capacitor will not be able to deliver the peak current and it might even be destroyed. Connecting capacitors in parallel will reduce the series resistance component.

2) Series inductance - a real capacitor has a non-trivial series inductance, which is usually in the $nH$ to $uH$ range. Together with the capacitance and the series resistance this will cause the capacitor to be self-resonant (it's a series LC circuit) in the $MHz-GHz$ range. Above the self-resonance frequency it will not behave like a capacitor, at all! Again, series inductance can be reduced by parallel configuration, but the self-resonance frequency will stay the same. If you need to do something about that (and trust me, many times you do), then you will have to work really hard by connecting many different capacitors with different resonance frequencies in parallel. There is quite a bit of an engineering art (and math) to that.

3) Leakage (usually described by a parallel resistance) - That's a problem for circuits that need to hold charge for a long time. The first thing there is material selection, of course, because the leakage time constant can not be changed by either series or parallel combinations (sometimes one can use a circuit trick to combine a low leakage and a high leakage capacitor together with an electronic amplifier to fake a high capacitance low leakage capacitor... but that's bordering on the desperate, I did it once, never want to do it, again).

4) Reliability - capacitors fail. When they fail in space or on the bottom of the ocean, your device (and often enough your career) is dead. If you can't allow that to happen, you have to analyze if the capacitor will fail open or closed, i.e. if it is more likely to lose some or all of its capacitance or to short out. Both can be mitigated with series (short) and parallel (open) circuits.

There are more "non-ideal" behaviors, like temperature dependence, triboelectricity etc. that can make your life hard... but like I said, go get the full download from the electrical engineers, they know this stuff too well.

Answer (score 1):

> in terms of making a better capacitor that can store more charge would
>   you use in series or in parallel?

To be sure, capacitors don't (ordinarily) store charge, capacitors store *energy*, i.e., a 'charged' capacitor is electrically neutral.

If, by better, you mean store more energy for a given voltage, then you want the combination of capacitors to be parallel connected.  That way, each capacitor has identical voltage and the energy stored *adds*:

$$W_\mathrm{total} = W_1 + W_2 = \frac{1}{2}C_1V^2 + \frac{1}{2}C_2V^2 = \frac{1}{2}V^2(C_1 + C_2)$$

See that the parallel connected capacitors store as much energy, for a given voltage, as one capacitor with capacitance $C = C_1 + C_2$; the capacitances add in parallel.

Now, if by better, you mean a combination with greater maximum voltage, then you might consider connecting the capacitors in series.  Assuming identical capacitors, the series connected pair can have twice$^*$ the total voltage across as a single capacitor.  Once again, the total energy stored is

$$W_\mathrm{total} = \frac{1}{2}C\left(\frac{V_\mathrm{total}}{2}\right)^2 + \frac{1}{2}C\left(\frac{V_\mathrm{total}}{2}\right)^2 = \frac{1}{2}V^2_\mathrm{total}\frac{C}{2}$$

The equivalent capacitance is 1/2 the individual capacitance so combining capacitors in series decreases the the equivalent capacitance.

$^*\:$In fact, some additional circuit elements may be required to 'equalize' the voltage across the series connected capacitors.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store more charge (assuming you're not increasing the voltage) you want more capacitance.  The way to do that is to put your two capacitors in parallel.$$C_{T}=C_{1}+C_{2}$$  If you think of each capacitor as pair of parallel you could imagine them in parallel as being side by side and effectively just adding the area of plates together to make bigger plates.

Putting them in series reduces the total capacitance.  Such that it will always be smaller than the smallest capacitor.$$\frac{1}{C_{T}}=\frac{1}{C_{1}}+\frac{1}{C_{2}}$$
It's not quite as intuitive as the parallel case but you can think of it as separating the spacing between the "outside" plates (the two that aren't wired together) which decreases the capacitance.

Comment: The useful effect you get from series is that the voltage drop across each component is lower.  You can put capacitors in series when your voltage requirement exceeds the rating for a single component.

Comment: Thanks! I was just looking up advantages of series capacitors at [Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/3062/what-are-some-reasons-to-connect-capacitors-in-series)

Answer (score 0):

Capacitors connected in series

$$\frac{1}{C_{\mathrm{total}}} = \frac{1}{C_1} + \frac{1}{C_2}$$
(Where $C$ is the capacitance)

Capacitors in parallel

$$ C_{\mathrm{total}} = C_1 + C_2$$

As you can see, capacitors are total opposite of resistors when connected in series or parallel

More capacitance or $C$ means the capacitor can store more charge.

As you can clearly see, if you have two capacitors and connect them in parallel then you can store more energy than u connect them in series.